# Extract a Time data from a table and put it into TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

Inside a table, does any1 know how to select a specified row and take a Time data in a specified column, then put the data inside TimeSpan?

```
DataRow[] selectIDRow = RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"].Select("ID=" + ID);
foreach (DataRow row in getTimeDifference)
{
    TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(); //Need to put the data into the bracket instead of using hard code

     TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(20, 00, 00); //Hard coded
     TimeSpan timeDifference = new TimeSpan();

     timeDifference = endTime.Subtract(startTime);

     double minutes = timeDifference.TotalMinutes;

     normalCount = minutes / 15;
```

Comment: What kind of format is your time data in the specified column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `TimeSpan.Parse()`?

```
DataRow[] selectIDRow = RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"].Select("ID=" + ID);
    foreach (DataRow row in getTimeDifference)
    {
         DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(row["DateTimeColumn"].ToString());
         TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(dateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
         ... //do whatever you want to do with timeSpan
    }
```

Comment: Thx for ur info, it can be used as reference in the future too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the text of the time column is well formatted, you can use `TimeSpan.Parse()`

```
TimeSpan startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(row["time"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I using TimeSpan.Parse(). Here's my code and it works! :)

```
foreach (DataRow row in RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"].Select("ID=" + convertedBranchID))
                {
                    var sTime = DateTime.Parse(row["SunFromTime"].ToString());
                    int sHour = sTime.Hour,
                        sMinute = sTime.Minute,
                        sSecond = sTime.Second;

                    var eTime = DateTime.Parse(row["SunToTime"].ToString());
                    int eHour = eTime.Hour,
                        eMinute = eTime.Minute,
                        eSecond = eTime.Second;

                    TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(sHour, sMinute, sSecond);
                    TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(eHour, eMinute, eSecond);
                    TimeSpan timeDifference = new TimeSpan();

                    timeDifference = endTime.Subtract(startTime);

                    double minutes = timeDifference.TotalMinutes;

                    normalCount = minutes / 15;
```